# Threadreference.isalive = true but in the threads window its location is [In a sleep, wait or join]

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, modal-dialog

I have a simple function that launches a thread with a modal form and then waits to the form to be closed.

```
private static bool GetSomeText()
    {
        Thread threadx = new Thread(GetSomeTextx);

        threadx.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        threadx.Start();

        int i = 0;
        const int secs = 6000;
        while (threadx.IsAlive && i < secs)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            i++;
        }

        if (i >= secs) //timeout
        {
            try
            {
                threadx.Abort();
            }
            catch { }

            MessageBox.Show("Timeout etc.");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return CheckText(Constants.inputedtext);
        }
    }

    private static void GetSomeTextx()
    {
        WindowWrapper window = new WindowWrapper(Fun.GetForegroundWindow());
        FormGetSomeText epa = new FormGetSomeText { displaytext=Constants.displaytext};
        epa.ShowDialog(window);
        Constants.inputedtext= epa.inputedtext;
    }
```

The problem is that after closing the window the thread exits GetSomeTextx() but remains in the limbo...
After that if i put a break in "while (threadx.IsAlive && i < secs)" i see that threadx.IsAlive its true and in the debug window the offending thread location is: [In a sleep, wait or join] and if i do a rightclick --> switch to thread it shows "No source Available" and clicking in Show Disassembly shows "No disassembly available."

This code is almost a 1:1 copy (in the other one there are 2 textboxes instead of 1) of another case that i have to get values this way and it works correctly...

What could it be?

Postdata: Tried already adding Thread.CurrentThread.Abort at the end of GetSomeTextx without result...

Comment: Turn on unmanaged debugging and enable the Microsoft symbol server.  Post the stack trace you now get if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait for the thread to complete, call [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx):

```
private static bool GetSomeText()
{
    Thread threadx = new Thread(GetSomeTextx);

    threadx.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    threadx.Start();

    // Wait for thread to exit
    threadx.Join();
```

If you want to support reporting when there's a timeout, call the `Join` overload that lets you specify timeout value.

Comment: Ironically i tried this method later after asking the question and it worked, but i would have liked to know why a working (if questionable) way to do it stopped doing so...